# There's a problem with this formula with Excel Scenarios in C#

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I am using Microsoft.Interop.Excel to collect summaries from different scenarios in a specific worksheet.

**C# code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Test_monte_carlo
{
    using Microsoft.Office.Core;
    using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
    static class Program
    {
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string input_filename = args[0];
        string output_filename = args[1];
        int test_run = Int32.Parse(args[2]);

        Console.WriteLine(input_filename);

        double averageS = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < test_run; i++)
        {
            Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application
            {
                Visible = true,
                DisplayAlerts = false 
            };

            Excel._Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Open(input_filename, UpdateLinks: 0, ReadOnly: false);
            workbook.Activate();
            Excel._Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets["Budget"];

            var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
            Excel.Scenarios sn = worksheet.Scenarios();
            Console.WriteLine(sn.Count);

            string resultcells = "B6";
            sn.CreateSummary(Excel.XlSummaryReportType.xlStandardSummary, resultcells);
            watch.Stop();

            workbook.SaveAs(output_filename);

            var elapsedS = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000.0;
            averageS = averageS + elapsedS;

            workbook.Close(false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            app.Quit(); 

            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbook);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(app);

            Console.WriteLine("Time " + i + ":" + elapsedS);
        }
        averageS = averageS / test_run;
        Console.WriteLine("Average time = " + averageS);
    }
} }
```

I am facing an error while running with the sample workbook,

*Unhandled Exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: There's a problem with this formula.
Not trying to type a formula?
When the first character is an equal ("=") or minus ("-") sign, Excel thinks it's a formula:
you type:   =1+1, cell shows:   2
To get around this, type an apostrophe ( ' ) first:
you type:   '=1+1, cell shows:   =1+1
at System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(String memberName, BindingFlags flags, Object target, Int32[] aWrapperTypes, MessageData& msgData)
at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Scenarios.CreateSummary(XlSummaryReportType ReportType, Object ResultCells)
at Test_monte_carlo.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\amduser\source\repos\Test_monte_carlo\Test_monte_carlo\Program.cs:line 51*

Any help here, please.
Hereby, I have attached the [link](https://www.contextures.com/xlscenario01.html) where I downloaded the xlsx file.

Answer (score 0):

`resultcells` is set to a string type but should be a range.

---

Try replacing `string resultcells = "B6";` with

```
Excel.Range resultcells = worksheet.Range["B6:B6"];
```